# "sudo su -" after login in Royal TS

Tags: sudo

I've setup Royal TS to automatically login using my username on several linux machines. I want to make it automatically run `sudo su -` after connect, enter my password, so I'm root after a simple double click on the connection.

I've managed to do this by creating a key sequence task like this:

```
{WAIT:1000}
sudo su -
{WAIT:500}
$this.EffectivePassword$
```

It works but the issue I'm having is that upon login the password is shown on the screen in clear. I've tried playing around with `{WAIT:1000}` but it's still shown.

Does anyone have a working example of how this should be configured?

Thanks!

Comment: Thinking about it from another angle, why not have NOPASSWD in your sudoers? Just to clarify, this means it won't be prompted for your password.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to become root, I've found a nice trick here:

https://royalapplications.uservoice.com/forums/310954-toolbox/suggestions/15222090-automating-sudo-password-confirmation-in-royal-tsx

In iTerm2 connection properties choose 'Triggers' and add new trigger:

```
Action: send text 
Regular expression: ^\[(sudo)\]\s(password)\s(for)\s($EffectiveUsername$)\:\s$(?!.)(?!\n) 
Parameters: $EffectivePassword$\n

Enable "Instant" checkbox 
Click add

Regular expression made for common linux sudo prompt, and will start to work in next connection.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Old post I know.
I took the easy way out and just clear the screen when done:

```
{WAIT:10}sudo -i{WAIT:10}{ENTER}$this.EffectivePassword${ENTER}
clear{ENTER}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the key sequence below to work. The principle is to do some keyboard task before putting the effective password. So I put abc characters and deleted it. Also remember that there is an implicit newline character after carriage returns.

```
{WAIT:500}sudo su - {WAIT:500}

{WAIT:100}abc{BACKSPACE}{BACKSPACE}{BACKSPACE}$this.EffectivePassword${ENTER}
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was just putting in another enter just like if you were actually typing the command out on a keyboard.  You type `sudo su` - then hit enter then type password then hit enter again. I had to have some wait but not as much as you had initially entered.

```
{WAIT:20}sudo su -{WAIT:10}{ENTER}$this.EffectivePassword${ENTER}
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this 4 yeas late, but if your password is showing you need to make sure its not entered in multiple places.

Comment: Not really an answer, but a recommendation loosely related to the question